# Consuming web services in android studio

Tags: ksoap2

I am trying to access a web service from android studio and generates an exeption when I make the call've read several tutorials've tried everything and nothing.

```
            final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.maticlot.com/TestWS";
            final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.maticlot.com/";
            final String METHOD_NAME = "TestWS";
            final String DIRURL = direccionIp + "/wsReportes.asmx";

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
            request.addProperty("Parametro","Pruebas");


            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.implicitTypes = true;
            envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
```

try {

```
                HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(DIRURL);
                transporte.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
                transporte.debug = true;

                transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);

                SoapPrimitive resultadoXML = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

                String resultado = resultadoXML.toString();
                Mensaje = resultado;
                textView03.setText("Paso Bien");
                //Montrar la respuesta en un Toast
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),resultado+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            catch (Exception e){

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Comment: Would halp if You append information about exception and xmls like request, response etc...

Comment: what kind of exception. paste your log